# Create a Pull Request as part of build step in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pull-request, azure-pipelines-build-task

We are using VSTS for our build server and for version control.

As part of our build process I would like to create a Pull Request from `master` branch to `develop` branch (for build running on `master` only). 
I know there is an [API endpoint](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/pull-requests/pull-requests#create-a-pull-request) to do that.

But I wonder if there is a better way to handle it? Like a custom step that does it (and I've missed it)?

Comment: I wonder what you are trying to achieve here. A more standard flow is to create a pull-request and have your build run after the pull-request has been completed. I always use 'Branch policies'. This allows you to protect your brach. One of the options is to add a build that has to pass to be able to complete the pull-request. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/branch-policies#require-a-successful-build

Comment: @E.Staal some devs in my team are lazy and don't merge bugfixes from where merged into `master` also into `develop`. And when time comes, `develop` branch is behind `master` for a lot of fixes and it can be a pain to merge later.

Comment: So, if you want changes to be merged to develop automaticly, why not skip master anyway? Another way to do this is to make this late integration visible on a monitor. Use the api to visualize who ‘forgot’ to merge his change to develop. Change the behavior instead of solving the result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install the [Create Pull Request](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ShaykiAbramczyk.CreatePullRequest) extension, it gives you the ability to create a pull request automatically from your build pipeline:

[image]

Comment: Oh, that's nice! A bit late for us, as we don't really have that problem anymore.

Comment: Hey, I know you!  You're the guy who made the Print All Variables extension!

Answer (score 1):

For now, there is no better way for that.

Even if you use a webhook to trigger the event when the build is successful for `master` branch, the main step is to use the [REST API to create a PR](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/pull-requests/pull-requests#create-a-pull-request). And there is no such extension task in marketplace.

But in the future, when the [server side hooks are available for VSTS](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/3895135-add-server-side-git-hooks), you can use post-push hook to update `develop` branch automatically after changes are merged from `bugfix` branch into `master` branch.

Comment: Thanks for confirming - VSTS API is easy enough to use, we'll probably go with it. Also we found this plugin: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kerwincarpede.GitflowBranchGate - it might help with what we are trying to do - just FYI.